# Why Is This For Loop Not Changing My Array of Objects? JS

Tags: javascript, jsx

Simple question, I am sure that I am being stupid and it is an easy fix. Have an array of objects and want to access each object's vis value and change it through my for loop. I don't understand why it doesn't work.

```
onSearch = keyWord => {
    let newMarkers = this.state.markers;
    for (let i = 0; i<this.state.markers.length;i++) {
      if (this.state.markers[i].name.toLowerCase().includes(keyWord.toLowerCase())) {
        newMarkers[i].vis = true;
      } else {
        newMarkers[i].vis = false;
      }
    }
    console.log(newMarkers);
    //console.log to see if the vis value has been changed: spoiler alert it hasn't :(
    this.setState({markers: newMarkers});

    console.log(this.state.markers)
  }
```

Comment: Console.log will never show the change to you since setState is async operation.

Comment: my newMarkers isn't changed either though and it doesn't use setState?

Comment: I had a typo from fiddling with it too much, it works now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Good to hear you found out the issue. Happy Learning!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setState` is asynchronous. Therefore you need to write the code as follows:

```
onSearch = keyWord => {
  let newMarkers = this.state.markers;
  for (let i = 0; i<this.state.markers.length;i++) {
    if (this.state.markers[i].name.toLowerCase().includes(keyWord.toLowerCase())) {
      newMarkers[i].vis = true;
    } else {
      newMarkers[i].vis = false;
    }
  }
  console.log(newMarkers);
  this.setState({markers: newMarkers}, () => {
    // use this callback function to do stuff AFTER state changes
    console.log(this.state.markers);
  });
}
```

Comment: I see, I will keep this in mind in the future, thank you!

Comment: @ZKJ this is the better answer, as it makes use of the intended API for setState as opposed to a hacky way of stein gifting/parsing data to make a copy.

Answer (score 2):

It keeps the state unchanged in your case. To overcome you might adapt a quick fix to this. Follow the code.

```
const jsonNewMarkers = JSON.stringify(newMarkers);
this.setState({markers: JSON.parse(jsonNewMarkers)}, () => {
  // use this callback function to do stuff AFTER state changes
  console.log(this.state.markers);
});
```

And please try the solution and let me know. It should work as mine it works.